# Conditional count of rows where at least one peer qualifies

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-filter

**Background**

I'm a novice SQL user. Using PostgreSQL 13 on Windows 10 locally, I have a table `t`:

```
+--+---------+-------+
|id|treatment|outcome|
+--+---------+-------+
|a |1        |0      |
|a |1        |1      |
|b |0        |1      |
|c |1        |0      |
|c |0        |1      |
|c |1        |1      |
+--+---------+-------+
```

**The Problem**

I didn't explain myself well initially, so I've rewritten the goal.

Desired result:

```
+-----------------------+-----+
|ever treated           |count|
+-----------------------+-----+
|0                      |1    |
|1                      |3    |
+-----------------------+-----+
```

First, identify `id` that have ever been treated. Being "ever treated" means having any row with `treatment = 1`.

Second, count rows with `outcome = 1` for each of those two groups. From my original table, the `id`s who are "ever treated" have a total of 3 `outcome` = 1, and the "never treated", so to speak, have 1 `outcome = 1.

**What I've tried**

I can get much of the way there, I think, with something like this:

```
select treatment, count(outcome)
from t
group by treatment;
```

But that only gets me this result:

```
+---------+-----+
|treatment|count|
+---------+-----+
|0        |2    |
|1        |4    |
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Hey @ErwinBrandstetter, sorry, got pulled away from the computer. See my **Edit** in the main post. I've tried to clarify what I want a bit. (Haven't tried your answer yet, though, I'll do that now.) I'm really asking for two things, I now realize: identify distinct `id` by a "ever treated" criterion, which I explain, and then sum the `outcome`=1 over each of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the updated question:

```sql
SELECT ever_treated, sum(outcome_ct) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , max(treatment) AS ever_treated
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE outcome = 1) AS outcome_ct
   FROM   t
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

```
 ever_treated | count 
--------------+-------
            0 |     1
            1 |     3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=501c022579ccaaf7640dbb59fce0444b)*

Read:

- For those who got no treatment at all (all `treatment = 0`), we see `1` x `outcome = 1`.
- For those who got any treatment (at least one `treatment = 1`), we see `3` x `outcome = 1`.

Would be simpler and faster with proper `boolean` values instead of `integer`.

Comment: Terrific, thanks so much. Apologies for muddling it on the first go! **Edit**: can I ask, as a novice, what would make `boolean` simpler? (I understand why it'd be faster.)

Answer (score 1):

**(Answer to updated question)**

here is an easy to follow subquery logic that works with integer:

```
    select subq.ever_treated, sum(subq.count) as count
    from (select id, max(treatment) as ever_treated, count(*) as count 
          from t where outcome = 1 
          group by id) as subq 
    group by subq.ever_treated;
```

Comment: Hey @Heidiki, I've just tried your solution and am realizing I didn't phrase my question well. Have a look at the **edit** I just made and see if that changes how you understood things. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this works well and is a lot easier to read than the other solution!