# What's the difference between WHERE and FILTER (WHERE) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

**Summary & Question**

I recently asked a [Postgres-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330880/conditional-count-of-rows-where-at-least-one-peer-qualifies) on SO and got a couple of different answers with queries that helped get me the result I wanted. Both of them worked, getting the correct result, and both had very similar code. One line was different, though: one answer used a `WHERE` clause to pick out something I'd asked for, and the other used `FILTER (WHERE ...)`. What's the difference between these two?

**Background Detail**

For the curious, the table I had asked about is this one:

```
+--+---------+-------+
|id|treatment|outcome|
+--+---------+-------+
|a |1        |0      |
|a |1        |1      |
|b |0        |1      |
|c |1        |0      |
|c |0        |1      |
|c |1        |1      |
+--+---------+-------+
```

I'd wanted something that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----+
|ever treated           |count|
+-----------------------+-----+
|0                      |1    |
|1                      |3    |
+-----------------------+-----+
```

And I got two answers that worked. Here's the first, from @ErwinBrandstetter:

```
SELECT ever_treated, sum(outcome_ct) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT id, 
          max(treatment) AS ever_treated, 
          count(*) FILTER (WHERE outcome = 1) AS outcome_ct
   FROM t
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

And here's @Heidiki with the second:

```
    select subq.ever_treated, sum(subq.count) as count
    from (select id, 
          max(treatment) as ever_treated, 
          count(*) as count from t where outcome = 1 
          group by id) as subq 
    group by subq.ever_treated;
```

To my (admittedly novice) eye, the main difference between the two is that in the former, you see this:

```
count(*) FILTER (WHERE outcome = 1) AS outcome_ct
```

While in the latter, you have this:

```
count(*) as count from t where outcome = 1
```

I'm looking through some of the documentation and I see that `FILTER` is working at the aggregate level, while perhaps `WHERE` is not, but I'm still lost on the intuition, especially as it applies to my table.

So what's the difference here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subqueries are not equivalent:

#### The first one

```
SELECT
  id, 
  max(treatment) AS ever_treated, 
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE outcome = 1) AS outcome_ct
FROM t
GROUP BY 1
```

1. Reads all the rows from `t`.
2. Computes the max `treatment` for every `id` in the **whole table** `t`.
3. Count the rows with `outcome = 1` for every `id`.

#### The second one

```
select
  id, 
  max(treatment) as ever_treated, 
  count(*) as count 
from t
where outcome = 1 
group by id
```

1. Reads the subset of rows from `t` where `outcome = 1`.
2. Computes the max `treatment` for every `id` in the **subset of the table** `t`.
3. Count the rows for every `id` in the subset (already filtered).

In terms of the result only #2 and #3 are significant. As you can see #3 will be equivalent, but #2 won't be.